# Calling grunt plugins from custom tasks

Tags: gruntjs

I want to compile a coffeescript file in custom grunt task that I am building. I want to be able to call grunt plugins from custom grunt tasks. This is the code that I am trying at this point:

```
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'

  grunt.registerTask('start', 'Starting compilation,', () ->
    grunt.log.write('Logging some stuff...').ok()
    grunt.coffee()
  )
```

My code is clearly wrong, but I am wondering how can I set the options of the coffee plugin and call it from this custom plugin. That way I'll be able to loop through and perform a custom compilation/build task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this (a dynamic alias task):

```
grunt.initConfig
  coffee: {}

grunt.registerTask 'start', 'Starting compilation,', ->
  grunt.log.write('Logging some stuff...').ok()
  grunt.config('coffee.target', { src: ['files'], dest: 'dist/out.js' })
  grunt.task.run(['coffee:target'])

grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
```

When entering `grunt start` it will configure the coffee task and then run it immediately after the `start` task has finished.